# Script# licencing

Tags: javascript, licensing, script#

Can I use script# in a commercial web project? And can I sell my product which includes script# files. I keep in mind .js files (mscorlib.js).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replied to Sergey via the email he sent.

The license for script# is available as part of the EULA step when installing the product. The sources are licensed under MS-PL currently.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that [this](http://www.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharpIntro.aspx) is what you're asking about, I would suggest you clarify the licensing with the author: http://www.nikhilk.net/Contact.aspx and ask him to add a licensing page to his site that explains it.